# Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY - Android

Tags: android

I got an error in my android app when I try to fetch data from server. This doesn't happen all the time. Some time I got the result correctly. It is in correct JSON format. Please help me on this issue.

**This is the Request**

```
@Rest(rootUrl = ApiBase, converters = {MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class}, interceptors = {LogInterceptor.class}, requestFactory = HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class)     
public interface ServerApi {

@Get("/getDetails?token={token}&isFavorite={favorite}&limit=25&offset=11&lat={lat}&long={lon}&distance={distance}&category={category}&isEndingSoon=0&isFlagship={flagship}&sort_by=in_mi&direction=ASC&storeId={store}&search={search}") 
DetailsResult getDetails(@Path String token, @Path int favorite, @Path double lat, @Path double lon, @Path int distance, @Path String search, @Path int category, @Path int flagship, @Path Integer store) throws RestClientException;

}
```

**And the Response is:**

```
E/API: ERROR: Could not read JSON: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7259675; line: 10950, column: 32])
           at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7259675; line: 10953, column: 503]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7259675; line: 10950, column: 32])
        at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7259675; line: 10953, column: 503]
```

Comment: add your result when you get error

Comment: please provide the your code !

Comment: Didn't get any result when error occurs. But when success got this kind of result
{
  “qqq_count": 335,
  “www_count": "708",
  “rrrr”: [
    {
      “xxx_id": 22,
      “xxx_name": "Electronics",
      "date_from": "2015-12-13 00:00:00",
      "date_to": "2017-06-30 00:00:00",
      "id": 5,
      "max_per_user": 1,
      "priority": 0,
      “yyy_limits": 10000,
      “qqq”: [
        290
      ],
      "title": “Test title“,
      "flagship": true,
      “yyy_period": 2678400
    }
],
"result": {
    "message": "ok",
    "isValid": true
  }
}

Comment: it seems that the json you try to read is not following the rules. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: Is the above JSON data in correct format?? @Opiatefuchs

Comment: can you please format the post? it´s hard to read like this...

Comment: Sorry @Opiatefuchs. It is updated now.

Comment: what´s that strange "L SEP" sign in the first line of your code?

Comment: "L SEP" ?? I didn't see such code.